# Woocommerce ajaxSuccess not detected

Tags: ajax, woocommerce

I have created a shortcode that displays products and I am listening to WooCommerce `added to cart` js event and trying to detect `ajaxSuccess`, so I can then add some custom js to the view cart button. The view cart button gets displayed after a product has been added to the cart without reloading the page (I have enabled fragments ajax refresh). However, the `ajaxSuccess` is not triggered for some reason and the code is not being executed. Here is the code I am using, it is working locally but not on the server, so I am quite puzzled:

```
// Adjust added to cart behavior for the homepage pattern for better ui
$( 'body' ).on( 'wc_fragments_loaded added_to_cart', function( ) {
    $( document ).ajaxSuccess( function( event, xhr, settings ) {
        if ( settings.url.indexOf( '?wc-ajax=add_to_cart' ) !== -1 ) {
            $( this.activeElement ).hide();
            $( this.activeElement ).next().addClass( 'add_to_cart_button wp-element-button' );
        }
    } );
} );
```

Comment: Updating WooCommerce to the latest version fixed the issue for me.